# Browser compatibility in responsive page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

`.content-block`  contain dynamic text. On browser resize height of heights `.content-block`  calculate and apply to other `.content-block` on page. Following pseudo code working in most of browser but in chrome browser size less than 320x480 its not working and content overlapping to other block.

```
function getMaxHeight(){
    return maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".content-block").map(function (){
        return $(this).height();
    }).get());
}

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.content-block').css('height', 'auto');
    $('.content-block').css('height', getMaxHeight);
});

$('.content-block').css('height', getMaxHeight);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, but anyways you do not need to test _desktop_ browsers for a viewport smaller than mobile devices. You don't really want to handle devices smaller than 320px, you really do not.

Comment: but its working in other browser ! page has content in `.content-block` one by one but height of every block is different so need to assign height same to each block. the pseudo use to calculate height in loop and assigned max height to all blocks